# Google Analytics 4 - purchase value is always 1

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

When someone does a purchase action on a website, I'm pushing this datalayer to GTM :

```
dataLayer.push({
  event: "purchase",
  ecommerce: {
    transaction_id: 559,
    currency: "USD",
    value: 200,
    tax: 0,
    items: [
      {item_id: 559, item_name: "Product 559", price: 200, quantity: 1}
    ]
  }
});
```

I can see from GTM debugger that all my data are correctly received.
Then, with GTM, I forward these data to GA4, as you can see in the picture attached.
[image: GTM configuration]

My problem is that, when it arrives in GA4, the "purchase" value is always equals to 1.
Everything else is okay, even the items, currency, etc... But the value is always received as = 1.

Would you have any idea of how to solve it?
THank you